# In Dragon Ball Super, what is the difference between "destroying" and "erasing"?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragonball-super

We have seen Freza and Bearus destroying planets, and we have seen Zen-oh sama erasing a universe in the "Future Trunks" arc. My question is, what is the difference between destroying and erasing?

Does erasing mean removing entirely from the time line itself?

---

My initial assumption was partially incorrect as Whis took Trunks back to his world (*in past to prevent Zamasu from killing anyone*) at the end of *Zamasu Arc*. So if the past of an entity is retained, what is the difference between Erasing and Destroying?

Answer (score 0):

If you are *erased* you do not die or live - you cease to exist, which has literally been said by Whis himself.

Being *destroyed* is similar: if you are *destroyed* you go to Heaven or Hell, but you still cannot be brought back with the *Super Dragon Balls*.

Comment: If you could improve upon your grammar and punctuation, it would go a long way toward improving the clarity of your answer.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You mentioned this was "literally said" by someone - do you have a source for this you could quote? That would improve your answer a lot. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Do you have a source for Super Dragon Balls not being able to revive someone that has gone to Heaven/Hell?

Answer (score 0):

- Frieza - With Frieza it is simple. He destroys a planet the people are killed. Able to come back.
- Beerus - If Beerus uses his Energy of Destruction, you are not coming back ever unless you are recreated.
- Zeno - Zeno erases your existence. Meaning that you aren't coming back until you are recreated.

Answer (score 0):

My conspiracy theory is, if you use the dragon balls to wish zen - oh to cease to exist and make yourself powerful, you basically gonna be a zen - oh too and if someone else uses the dragon balls and wishes you to cease to exist and make himself or herself powerful which means he or she will become a zen - oh too

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I don't understand how this explains how "destroying" differs from "erasing.". Please only post answers that answer the question; this seems to just be a comment.  You might want to read [answer] and take the [tour].

Answer (score -2):

Just a guess, but it might be that if you are erased you don't go to hell nor to heaven. You just ceased to exist.

If you die or are killed you will go to heaven or hell as seen on DBZ.

So maybe if you are erased, they cant bring you back with normal Dragon Balls.